# How can I install the Zabbix agent without yum on RHEL 6?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I am testing Zabbix locally on CentOS 6 but this will be installed and configured on Red Hat without having yum.

All the instructions I have found online give me guides for yum.

Is there a package or can someone help me manually package this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 way to install zabbix agent without yum:

1. Compile and install zabbix agent from source code https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/installation/installation_from_source
2. Install zabbix agent rpm and its dependecies using the rpm command (rpm -ivh rpmfile.... )
3. Extract files from zabbix agent rpm http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html and copy them on your machine. You have to check if the zabbix agent rpm contains some pre or post install script http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-list-package-specific-scriptlets/ . In this case you need to check any dependency of the rpm and install them

Comment: Thanks I tried #2 which says failed dependencies - zabbix is needed by zabbix-agent-2.4.4-1.el6x86_64. I will look at #1 or #3.

Comment: If you can use rpm the second option is the most easy and clean. Use a test system with yum in order to download zabbix agent rpm and their dependencies following this guide http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/02/22/yum-command-to-download-rpm-file-without-installing-in-linux-system/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install from sources. Here is link for version 2.4, you can select your version from the top of page. That link has agent config part as well.

`https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/installation/install`